# MySQL Syntax error from INSERT INTO email address

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble inserting an email address into a MySQL database.  I'm getting the dreaded 1064 error like so..

*Error creating new user You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@email.com, password, 20)' at line 1 -- 1064*

So I'm guessing I need to escape the @ in the email variable?  But nothing i do seems to please Maria.  Generating the query in PHPMyAdmin was no help either.
Any advice gratefully accepted.

```
// update SQL
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, balance) VALUES ($new_player, $new_email, $new_password, 20)";
    if ($db->query($sql2) == TRUE) {
            echo "** New User Created **<BR>";
                } else {
                echo "Error creating new user " . $db->error." -- ". $db->errno ."<BR>";
    }
```

Comment: Strings need to be quoted. You should use parameterized queries. Also hopefully that password is hashed.

Comment: In your values, change them to: ('$new_player', '$new_email', '$new_password', 20). That will work when entering into the database.

Comment: That's true, OP should think about using a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Hi all and thanks.  this is nothing important, it's just a learning exercise for me.  But I will look into using prepared statements.
Quoting the Variable worked.  I thought i needed to escape them first as that's what PHPMyAdmin was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your values to use quotes should fix this specific problem. However to prevent SQL injections you should use a prepared statement. The prepared statement will go as below:

```
$sql2 = INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, balance) VALUES (?,?,?,20)";
$pStmt = $db->prepare($sql2);
$pStmt->bind_param("sss", $username,$email, $password);
$pStmt->execute();
```

If you are sure you want to use your present setup because you're in a test environment or you specifically need it, changing your query to this will work:

```
$sql2=INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, balance) VALUES ('$new_player', '$new_email', '$new_password', 20);
```

Comment: in prepared statement wquery , you don't use balance value???

Comment: @MohitKumar my bad, I missed it, just fixed it!

Comment: If it helped, can you please accept it as the answer. @noisy andrew